# Django - NoReverseMatch error with two slugs into a template URL

Tags: django, django-templates

I am creating a Django site where the URL's feature multiple slugs:

```
www.example.com/app-name/country_slug/area_slug
```

E.g.

```
www.example.com/destinations/united-states/new-york
```

I have the URL pattern working fine using this code in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<slug:country_slug>/', views.CountryView.as_view(), name='country'),
    path('<slug:country_slug>/<slug:area_slug>/', views.AreaView.as_view(), name='area'),
]
```

If I enter the url into the browser address bar, I can access the page without problems.
The issue comes with the template for the view 'country'.  I am struggling to create a link to the 'area' page, as this need to reference both the 'country_slug' and 'area_slug' in the {% url %} tag.  Here is the error I am getting:

```
NoReverseMatch at /destinations/united-states/
Reverse for 'area' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['destinations/(?P<country_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<area_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

Here is the code I am using in the template:

```
{% if latest_area_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for area in latest_area_list %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'destinations:area' country.country_slug area.area_slug %}">{{ area.area_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And the View:

```
class CountryView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'destinations/country.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_area_list'
    slug_field = 'country_slug'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'country_slug'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.country = get_object_or_404(Country, country_slug=self.kwargs['country_slug'])
        return Area.objects.filter(country=self.country)

class AreaView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'destinations/area.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_place_list'
    slug_field = 'area_slug'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'area_slug'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.area = get_object_or_404(Area, area_slug=self.kwargs['area_slug'])
        return Place.objects.filter(area=self.area)
```

And the models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    country_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name

class Area(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    area_name = models.CharField(max_length=50
    area_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.area_name
```

It seems the 'country_slug' and 'area_slug' are being passed through to the URL patterns just fine, but this is not getting passed through to the template.

It might be worth noting that:

- The code worked fine when there was just 1 dynamic slug in the URL, the issue has come with including 2 slugs in a single URL.
- If I comment out the hyperlink in the template, the page loads without an error.  So the issue is clearly with the link in the template.

I am quite new to Django so any help you can provide with this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyword synthax like in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

```
{% url 'destinations:area' country_slug=country.country.slug area_slug=area.area_slug %}
```

Comment: This unfortunately is still giving me an error.  It seems 'country_slug' is an empty string, and not accessing the object correctly?  

This is the error message: 
NoReverseMatch at /destinations/united-states/
Reverse for 'area' with keyword arguments '{'country_slug': '', 'area_slug': 'new-york'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['destinations/(?P<country_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<area_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']